# Variable Hiding in OCaml's Pattern Matching

Tags: ocaml

I have a method that returns the count of the most common element in a list (specifically a list of char values)

Here's my code:

```ml
let getMostFrequentCharCount li =
  let hashTable = Hashtbl.create (List.length li) in
  let rec getMostFrequentCharCount li acc =
    match li with
      [] -> acc
    | head::tail ->
      (match (Hashtbl.find hashTable head) with
         exception Not_found -> Hashtbl.add hashTable head 1
       | _ -> 
         let currentFreq = Hashtbl.find hashTable head in
         Hashtbl.replace hashTable head (currentFreq+1));
         let currentFreq = Hashtbl.find hashTable head in
         if currentFreq > acc then
           getMostFrequentCharCount tail currentFreq
         else
           getMostFrequentCharCount tail acc
  in
  getMostFrequentCharCount li 0;;
```

For some reason, when I remove the parentheses surrounding the second pattern matching block (starts with `match (Hashtbl.find hashTable head) with`), my compiler complains that my accumulator `acc` has type unit in the next if-statement `if currentFreq > acc` when `acc` should have type `int`.

Why are the parentheses fixing this error?

Answer (score 2):

In OCaml syntax, a `match` branch (after `->`) contains a *sequence* of expressions separated by `;`. Therefore without the parentheses, the following lines are parsed as part of the `match` branch for `_`.

Since `Hashtbl.add` returns unit, the first branch of this match is of type unit. This means the `_` branch must also be of type unit. When you don't have the parentheses, the following lines cause a type error because they're not of type unit.

I used ocamlformat to format the outer `match` with and without the parentheses.

Here is the formatted code with parentheses:

```
match li with
| [] -> acc
| head :: tail ->
    ( match Hashtbl.find hashTable head with
    | exception Not_found -> Hashtbl.add hashTable head 1
    | _ ->
        let currentFreq = Hashtbl.find hashTable head in
        Hashtbl.replace hashTable head (currentFreq + 1) );
    let currentFreq = Hashtbl.find hashTable head in
    if currentFreq > acc then getMostFrequentCharCount tail currentFreq
    else getMostFrequentCharCount tail acc
```

Here is the formatted code without parentheses:

```
match li with
| [] -> acc
| head :: tail -> (
    match Hashtbl.find hashTable head with
    | exception Not_found -> Hashtbl.add hashTable head 1
    | _ ->
        let currentFreq = Hashtbl.find hashTable head in
        Hashtbl.replace hashTable head (currentFreq + 1);
        let currentFreq = Hashtbl.find hashTable head in
        if currentFreq > acc then getMostFrequentCharCount tail currentFreq
        else getMostFrequentCharCount tail acc )
```

I think this does a pretty good job of illustrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation; it's very helpful! I'm now wondering though, why is `acc` assumed to be of type unit when the if-statement `if currentFreq > acc` is not a return statement of the corresponding `match` branch?

Comment: Consider the second version above without parentheses.  All branches of a `match` must (of course) have the same type. So `acc` must have whatever is the type of the nested `match`. The first branch of the nested `match` clearly has type unit. So `acc` must have type unit. Since it's compared to `currentFreq` in `currentFreq > acc` it must also have type int. This is a type error. The analysis decided on unit type for `acc` first, so that's how the message is worded.

Comment: But if a `match` branch is defined as a sequence (following the `->`) of 1 or more expressions separated by `;`, and the said sequence must return the same type as all other branches in the `match` block, why is `acc` (within that if-statement expression) considered the return value (for the branch matching `_`) that needs to be of type unit when the return value is either  `getMostFrequentCharCount tail currentFreq` or `getMostFrequentCharCount tail acc`

Comment: It's not possible to have a complicated discussion down here in the comments. I can add more to the answer if you like. But to answer quickly: the analysis has to work in some order. There are three things that need to be the same type: `acc`, `Hashtbl.add`, and the expression you mention. The analysis can proceed by assuming the first two are the same type. I.e., it can start by assuming that `acc` is of type unit. If the code is correctly typed, the order doesn't matter. If not, you can get different errors depending on the order the analysis happens to take.

Comment: Oh wait I think I get it. Without parentheses, the `match` branch corresponding to `exception Not_found` returns a unit type, so the compiler assumes that the *outer* `match` branch (corresponding to `[]`) returns a unit type as well which is stored in variable `acc`. So now that the compiler has assumed `acc` is a unit type at this point, the compiler gets confused when `acc` is in the if-statement when `acc` is not an int type. Is this what you meant?